# scatter_nd_add() example for sparse addition in TensroFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, sparse-matrix

I am having difficulty applying `tf.scatter_nd_add()` to 2D tensors. The documentation is a bit unclear and has does not contain an example for sparse update but only for full slice updates.

My case is the following:

- `updates` - 2D tensor of shape `[None, 6]`
- `indices` - 2D tensor  of shape `[None, 6]`
- `ref` - 2D Variable of zeros of shape `[None, 6]`

It is guaranteed that `updates`, `indices` and `ref` will always have their first dimension equal, but the size of that dimension can be varying. The update I want to perform looks like

```
for i, j:
    k = indices[i][j]
    ref[i][k] += updates[i][j]
```

Note that `indices` contains duplicates. `tf.scatter_nd_add(ref, indices, updates)` complains about shape mismatch and I cannot figure out how I need to restructure the tensors in order to performs the update.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Each 2D entry in `indices` must actually specify the absolute location that will get updated in `ref`. This means that `indices` must be 3D and then the non-vectorized update looks like:

```
for i, j:
    r, k = indices[i][j]
    ref[r][k] += updates[i][j]
```

In the above question it just happens that `r` is always equal to `i`.

Here is a full Tensorflow implementation with varying shapes. For clarity, in the following example, `col_indices` corresponds to `indices` from the original question:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

updates     = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,  shape=[None, 6])
col_indices = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32,    shape=[None, 6])
row_indices = tf.cumsum(tf.ones_like(col_indices), axis=0, exclusive=True)
indices     = tf.concat([tf.expand_dims(row_indices, axis=-1), 
                         tf.expand_dims(col_indices, axis=-1)], axis=-1)

tmp_var     = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False, dtype=tf.float32, validate_shape=False)
ref         = tf.assign(tmp_var, tf.zeros_like(updates), validate_shape=False)
# This makes sure that ref is always 0 before scatter_nd_add() runs
with tf.control_dependencies([target_var]):
  result = tf.scatter_nd_add(ref, indices, updates)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

# Create example input data 
np_input = np.arange(0, 6, 1, dtype=np.int32)
np_input = np.tile(np_input[None,:], [10, 1])

res = sess.run(result, feed_dict={updates: np_input, col_indices: np_input})
print(res)
```